# Find duplicates in column 1 and remove column 1 and two

Tags: excel, duplicates

### The problem

My table looks like this:

```
Email               | Name
test@example.com    | Test
info@example.com    | Lorum
info@example.com    | Ipsum
bot@example.com     | Bot
```

Now, I want to find the duplicates in column 1 called `Email` and then remove all duplicates except the first entry, so the output has to be:

```
Email               | Name
test@example.com    | Test
info@example.com    | Lorum
bot@example.com     | Bot
```

---

### What I've tried

I added a new row with the this:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A, A1);
```

This will add the number of duplicates in the third column, then I remove all the duplicates manually, which takes too much time to do everyday..

---

### The question

Can anyone point me in a good direction to do it in a quick way? Is their an easy solution based on a VB script or something? Or maybe a hidden feature in Excel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Excel 2010 (I think also 2007) You can remove duplicates by selecting all the data, going to the 'Data' tab in the menu, and then pressing 'Remove Duplicates'

Make sure you only have the 'Email' box ticked as column, and press OK.

This will keep the first (Highest in the list) entry of the email, and erase the whole row of the duplicates after.

Comment: Ok, very stupid, I thought it was only possible to remove duplicates of both columns with that function.. Thank you very much for your quick answer.